# Exactness of a term after taking Pontryagin dual: a step in the proof of Poitou-Tate duality

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, duality, galois-cohomology

I'm reading the proof of Poitou-Tate duality in the book Galois Cohomology and Class Field Theory by David Harari.

After some arguments, we get a exact sequence

$$ 
   \mathbf{P}^1_S(k,M^{'})^* \longrightarrow   H^1(G_S,M^{'})^* \longrightarrow \text{Ш}_S^2(k,M) \longrightarrow0
$$
and the author said it shows that  $Ш^2_S(k,M)$ is the dual of $Ш^1_S(k,M^{'})$, *which I can't understand.*

Since $Ш^1_S(k,M^{'})$ is defined as the kernel of $ H^1(G_S,M^{'})\to \mathbf{P}^1_S(k,M^{'})$, that is, we have  $$0 \to Ш^1_S(k,M^{'})\to H^1(G_S,M^{'})\to \mathbf{P}^1_S(k,M^{'})$$

After taking Pontryagin duality, we have

$$ 
   \mathbf{P}^1_S(k,M^{'})^* \longrightarrow   H^1(G_S,M^{'})^* \longrightarrow \text{Ш}_S^1(k,M^{'})^* \longrightarrow 0
$$

If we could show this complex is also exact, then we can conclude $Ш^2_S(k,M) \cong Ш^1_S(k,M^{'})^*$ as cokernel of a same morphism. Now the exactness at $Ш^1_S(k,M^{'})$ is because $\mathbf{Q}/\mathbf{Z}$ is injective module, but I can't show the exactness at the middle term.

( Pontryagin dual in this book is defined as $G^*:=\mathrm{Hom}_{contiuous}(G,\mathbf{Q}/\mathbf{Z})$, but $\mathbf{Q}/\mathbf{Z}$ is viewed as a discrete group in the Notations and Conventions at beginning of the book, which confuse me again because the Euclidean topology is more natrual to me. I hope the conclusion is still valid if $\mathbf{Q}/\mathbf{Z}$ is given Euclidean topology, but I don't know if it's true)

Thanks for any help!

Edit: All the $\mathbf{P}^1_S(k,M)$ should be $\mathbf{P}^1_S(k,M^{'})$, I corrected them and sorry for my mistakes.

Edit2：Here $M$ is assumed to be finite, but $S$ could be infinite.

Comment: Is $M$ finite? Is $S$ finite? If so then all groups in these sequences are finite and Pontyagin duality is exact.
Why it does not matter for these cohomology groups, if we take $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ with the discrete topology, look at the remark after Theorem 1.1.8 in "Cohomology of number fields".

Comment: @ChrisWuthrich  $M$ is finite, but $S$ is not assumed to be finite.

Comment: It is true for finite $S$ and then take the limit. See the Theorem 1.1.8. mentioned above which states Pontryagin duality with all details.